# time series automate labeling based on value per day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, append

I would like to use point reference data and turn it into a type that is time-series analysable.
My data has start_date and end_date, which I used to calculate the duration of the event (if start and end_date on same day, return 1. Duration values range between 0 to 326).

Furthermore, I have another pd dataframe which is a flattened series of images sized x*y, which has (among others) three columns: time, lon(x), lat(y).

Now, I would like to append to the latter dataset a True boolean if the date falls inside (start_date + duration). Else, return False.

Below I have created some example data out the required output to visualise what I would like to achieve. Does someone know how to approach this issue?

Next,  I would like to add true labels to the rows that fall within that duration. See the example of my data with the required output. Does somebody know how I should tackle this issue?

```
pd.DataFrame({'lat':[50,60], 
          'long':[-120,-110], 
          'time':[np.datetime64('2020-01-01'),np.datetime64('2020-05-06')],
          'end_time':[np.datetime64('2020-01-04'),np.datetime64('2020-05-06')],
          'duration':[4,1]})


    lat lon     time        end_time    duration
0   50  -120    2020-01-01  2020-01-04  4
x   60  -110    2020-05-06  2020-05-06  1
```

Required output would look like:

```
    lat lon     time        label
0   50  -120    2020-01-01  True
1   50  -120    2020-01-02  True
2   50  -120    2020-01-03  True
3   50  -120    2020-01-04  True
4   50  -120    2020-01-05  False
...
x-1 60  -110    2020-05-05  False
x   60  -110    2020-05-06  True
x+1 60  -110    2020-05-07  False
```

Edit: Below is the an example of how my data is really structured:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [np.datetime64('2002-05-18'),np.datetime64('2002-05-18'),np.datetime64('2002-05-18'),np.datetime64('2002-05-18'),np.datetime64('2002-05-18')],
                   'lon': [-116.125, -115.875, -115.625, -115.375, -115.125],
                   'lat': [55.125, 55.125, 55.125, 55.125, 55.125],
                   'out_date': [np.datetime64('2002-05-19'), None, None, None, None],
                   'duration_days': [2, None, None, None, None],
                   'Fire': [True, None, None, None, None],
                   'size_ha': [0.1, None, None, None, None],
                   'fire_count': [1, None, None, None, None]})

    time        lon         lat     out_date    duration_days   Fire    size_ha fire_count
0   2002-05-18  -116.125    55.125  2002-05-19  2.0             True    0.1     1.0
1   2002-05-18  -115.875    55.125  NaT         NaN             None    NaN     NaN
2   2002-05-18  -115.625    55.125  NaT         NaN             None    NaN     NaN
3   2002-05-18  -115.375    55.125  NaT         NaN             None    NaN     NaN
4   2002-05-18  -115.125    55.125  NaT         NaN             None    NaN     NaN
```

Each day has 42x46 combinations of `lon, lat`, which are passed before going to the next day. In the newly added table you see a forest fire occured on `'time': 2002-05-18` with coordinates x and y has a duration of 2. I would like to see that if I would now go 1932 (42x46) rows down to `'time': 2002-05-19` to see the column 'fire' (which is a label) updated to `True`. Say we group by lon and lat, the data would look the data in the 'required output' example dataframe.

Comment: `I have another pd dataframe which is a flattened series of images sized x*y,` - can you post it?

Comment: So that dataset is the second table you see under 'required output', which for now includes lat,lon,time. However, I want to add the Label column to it using the data from the first dataframe

Comment: Super, so solution should working well. If not, please post 3-5 rows of this DataFrame.

Comment: I tried your solution but it did not seem to work. Therefore, I have added some additional information and 5 rows of my dataframe. Hope this makes it more clear for you what I am looking for

Comment: Some problem with solution?

Comment: Using the newly added dataframe which consists of actual rows of my table I get the following error. 
ValueError: repeats may not contain negative values.

Comment: So `ValueError: repeats may not contain negative values.` means some datetime from `end_time` are less like `time` column

Comment: Added EDIT to answer for solving this problem.

Comment: Thanks! Just saw your 'corrected' answer. It works now! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert both columns to datetimes and add one day to `end_date`, then repeat index by [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with subtraction of days and add counter values by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df['end_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_time']) + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')

s = df.pop('end_time').sub(df['time']).dt.days
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(s)].copy()
counter = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
df['time'] = df['time'].add(pd.to_timedelta(counter, unit='d'))
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   lat  long       time  duration
0   50  -120 2020-01-01         4
1   50  -120 2020-01-02         4
2   50  -120 2020-01-03         4
3   50  -120 2020-01-04         4
4   60  -110 2020-05-06         1
```

And then merge by another `DataFrame` with left join and `indicator` parameter, last compare by `both`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'time': [np.datetime64('2020-01-03'),np.datetime64('2002-05-18'),
                             np.datetime64('2002-05-18'),np.datetime64('2002-05-18'),
                             np.datetime64('2002-05-18')],
                   'lon': [-120, -115.875, -115.625, -115.375, -115.125],
                   'lat': [50, 55.125, 55.125, 55.125, 55.125],
                   'out_date': [np.datetime64('2002-05-19'), None, None, None, None],
                   'duration_days': [2, None, None, None, None],
                   'Fire': [True, None, None, None, None],
                   'size_ha': [0.1, None, None, None, None],
                   'fire_count': [1, None, None, None, None]})
```

---

```
df = (df1.rename(columns={'lon':'long'})
         .merge(df, 
                on=['lat','long','time'], 
                indicator='label', 
                how='left'))
df['label'] = df['label'].eq('both')
print (df)
        time     long     lat   out_date  duration_days  Fire  size_ha  \
0 2020-01-03 -120.000  50.000 2002-05-19            2.0  True      0.1   
1 2002-05-18 -115.875  55.125        NaT            NaN  None      NaN   
2 2002-05-18 -115.625  55.125        NaT            NaN  None      NaN   
3 2002-05-18 -115.375  55.125        NaT            NaN  None      NaN   
4 2002-05-18 -115.125  55.125        NaT            NaN  None      NaN   

   fire_count  duration  label  
0         1.0       4.0   True  
1         NaN       NaN  False  
2         NaN       NaN  False  
3         NaN       NaN  False  
4         NaN       NaN  False
```

EDIT: If error:

> ValueError: repeats may not contain negative values

It means some row with `end_time` is lower like `time` column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lat':[50,60], 
          'long':[-120,-110], 
          'time':[np.datetime64('2020-01-01'),np.datetime64('2020-05-06')],
          'end_time':[np.datetime64('2020-01-04'),np.datetime64('2020-05-04')],
          'duration':[4,1]})

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df['end_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_time']) 
print (df)
   lat  long       time   end_time  duration
0   50  -120 2020-01-01 2020-01-04         4
1   60  -110 2020-05-06 2020-05-04         1 end_time  < time
```

Possible solution is swap these values:

```
m = df['time'].gt(df['end_time'])
d = {'end_time':'time','time':'end_time'}
df.loc[m, ['time','end_time']] = df.loc[m, ['end_time','time']].rename(columns=d)

df['end_time'] = df['end_time']  + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')
print (df)
   lat  long       time   end_time  duration
0   50  -120 2020-01-01 2020-01-05         4
1   60  -110 2020-05-04 2020-05-07         1
```

And then use solution above:

```
s = df.pop('end_time').sub(df['time']).dt.days
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(s)].copy()
counter = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
df['time'] = df['time'].add(pd.to_timedelta(counter, unit='d'))
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   lat  long       time  duration
0   50  -120 2020-01-01         4
1   50  -120 2020-01-02         4
2   50  -120 2020-01-03         4
3   50  -120 2020-01-04         4
4   60  -110 2020-05-04         1
5   60  -110 2020-05-05         1
6   60  -110 2020-05-06         1
```